# Rails 3.2 + MySQL: Error: Field 'created_at' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, timestamp, insert-into

I created a new migration, where is mentioned

```
...
t.timestamps
```

in the created table are added these two columns

```
...
| created_at  | datetime   | NO (Null)  |     | NULL (Default)   |                
| updated_at  | datetime   | NO (Null)  |     | NULL (Default)   |
...
```

When I want to create a new item, I always get the error message

```
Mysql2::Error: Field 'created_at' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO `table_name` (`first_col`, `second_col`) VALUES ('a', 'b')
```

Am I missing something? I sent this miniapp to a friend of mine and he is able to run successfully run it -> the record is created in database.

What am I missing?

Comment: How are you creating the new item?

Comment: `@photo = Photo.new(params[:photo])` ... `@photo.save`

Answer (score 17):

I just ran into something similar on a fresh install of MySql on Mac OS.

I finally narrowed it down to the combination of newer versions of MySql turning on "strict mode" by default, and my project having a table with some questionable constraints on it.  The table in question was the "join table" used in a `:has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship.  Somehow that table had been created with `:created_at`, and `:updated_at` attributes that had a constraint of `:null => false` on them.  Rails 3.2 doesn't automatically populate the timestamp fields for join tables of `:habtm` relationships.  When strict mode is turned off MySql will just populate the cols with zeroed out dates, like `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.  With strict mode turned on it raises an exception.

To fix the issue I ran a migration to allow the timestamp fields to be null.  Like this:

```
class ChangeNullableForTimestampsOnThing1sThing2s < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    change_column(:thing1s_thing2s, :created_at, :datetime, :null => true)
    change_column(:thing1s_thing2s, :updated_at, :datetime, :null => true)
  end

  def down
    change_column(:thing1s_thing2s, :created_at, :datetime, :null => false)
    change_column(:thing1s_thing2s, :updated_at, :datetime, :null => false)
  end
end
```

Honestly, it's probably better to just drop the columns if you don't need them, but we have a couple of special cases where they actually get set manually.

Comment: Very helpful thank you. I hope they fix this soon. Here is more of a discussion on the issue: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/10307

Answer (score 5):

to add to Jeremy's answer, on a mac you can remove strict mode with

```
> vi /usr/local/opt/mysql/my.cnf
```

then replace

```
sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

with

```
sql-mode="NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```