# Getting errors with Minitest when I have a timestamp for a has many through jointable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, has-and-belongs-to-many, minitest, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a join table for a has many and belongs to many through, the join table including many other attributes has a timestamp, implementation wise there is no trouble,

User

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :affiliations
  has_many :organizations, through: :affiliations

end
```

Organization

```
class Organization < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :affiliations
  has_many :users, through: :affiliations

end
```

Affiliation

```
class Affiliation < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :organization

  has_many :xxxxxs
end
```

Affiliation stores not just the belongs, it itself holds information like what the user's rank and what not is in the organization. It is pretty much a strong model of its own.

For fixtures, I do not have a file for the jointable yet,

user.yml

> ```
> user1:
>   email: aaa@aaa.com
>   organizations: org1
> ```

organization.yml

> ```
> org1
>   name: foo
> ```

but when I run tests using minitest, it gives me an error.

```
Error:
PublicControllerTest#test_should_get_index:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Field 'created_at' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO `affiliations` (`user_id`, `dominion_id`) VALUES (794918725, 299359653)
```

Odd thing is, it occurs on tests that don't even use the said table,

```
class PublicControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

  test "should get index" do
    get :index
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

This action does absolutely nothing, at this point its just plain html

```
class PublicController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end
```

does nothing in the controller.

They go away when a remove the timestamps, but recording when the association was created is necessary information. Is there something I need to do in the tests?

I am using Rails edge (5.0.0rc1) is there any chance that this is causing the errors?

Comment: Could you put the test by minitest which produces the error? And maybe exact line that causes it?

Comment: Also - does creation of the same jointable record in your "normal" Rails code works? I.e. is the error specific to minitest run only, and not other code?

Comment: added models, complete error, actual test, and the controller that it tests, and yes, as code in the project, the whole thing works without any problem

Comment: And what if you completely remove  get :index from test - will it fail? Can you check fixtures on whether they may contain wrong (old) data?

Comment: It seems having timestamps will cause all the test that exists fail regardless, as for fixtures I do not have any for affiliation at the moment, since current tests do not cover its actions, I just create the has_many through it.

Comment: so you have "organizations: org1" for your user1 in fixtures - can this cause the issue? what if you remove that? because user can be connected to org only through your joint table, right?

Comment: still getting errors, for now I've removed timestamps to get on with writing test cases and a lot of stuff has changed, putting timestamps back is giving me a different error, ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError

Comment: Btw, thank you for your time in looking into this, must appreciated.

Comment: Oh wait, yes that did take care of it, ....I guess a has man through fixutres doesn't work as a normal association, If you could update the answer, I will mark it as the answer.

Comment: Updated in main answer. Also see if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16548352/rails-dont-generate-create-at-for-fixture) question may help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 3.**

Having *"organizations: org1"* for your user1 in fixtures seed data - seems this is causing the issue, because user can be connected to organization only through your joint table.

I didn't find anything explicit in spec, but something relevant [here](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2014/09/21/tricks-and-tips-for-using-fixtures-in-rails.html)

> Fixtures bypass the normal Active Record object creation process.
>   After reading them from YAML file, they are inserted into database
>   directly using insert query. So they skip callbacks and validations
>   check. This also has an interesting side-effect which can be used for
>   drying up fixtures.

**Update 2.**

I was wrong at assumption that you can't have timestamps in has_and_belongs_to_many jointable managed by Rails. In fact, inside HasAndBelongsToMany Rails will create an ActiveRecord::Base class for that table - [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/1a5fdf77122e32fc710148ea3e795fedb597ad46/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/builder/has_and_belongs_to_many.rb#L44)

```
def through_model
   habtm = JoinTableResolver.build lhs_model, association_name, options
   join_model = Class.new(ActiveRecord::Base) {
     class << self;
     ...
```

And ActiveRecord::Base include Timestamp [module](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb)

So your error should be caused by some other way of creating an entry in jointable other then standard Rails association.

---

**Original**.

I don't believe that you can have automatically managed timestamp fields in jointable for has_and_belongs_to_many relation in ActiveRecord. This didn't (intentionally) work in old Rails (e.g. 3.2 - link below), and it don't sound like it changed recently.

If you want to have extended join table, you may create a dedicated ActiveRecord model for it and use use has_many :through association. This way it will automatically support timestamps should you add it to table definition.

See https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/4653 for timestamps on HABTM jointable

> AFAICT Rails 3.1 does not populate timestamps on a join table. The
>   only difference is that in 3.2, when you add timestamps, they are
>   marked as NOT NULL.
>
> @veganstraightedge the timestamps didn't "work" in 3.1 - they just
>   didn't raise an error when the join table was saved with them as null.
>   the difference here is that in 3.2 timestamps are created with a NOT
>   NULL constraint.

Basically, this can come from an idea that you don't have ActiveRecord model class for the jointable (*update 2* - actually you have!), and timestamps are feature of ActiveRecord model. Timestamps in Rails 5.0rc1 hasn't changed a lot - [sources](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.0.0.rc1/activerecord/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb#L56) - Timestamp is a module that extends ActiveRecord class.

By the way, it's now suggested to use create_join_table migration helper that will create "pure" table (two id's only, no timestamps):
https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/4726

SO *Question* with similiar error - [Rails 3.2 + MySQL: Error: Field 'created_at' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16199710/rails-3-2-mysql-error-field-created-at-doesnt-have-a-default-value-inser)

> Rails 3.2 doesn't automatically populate the timestamp fields for join
>   tables of :habtm relationships.

---

**Alternatively** (warning - theory!), you can try using either Association callbacks or Association extensions - http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

> Association callbacks
>
> Similar to the normal callbacks that hook into the life cycle of an
>   Active Record object, you can also define callbacks that get triggered
>   when you add an object to or remove an object from an association
>   collection.

```
class Project
  has_and_belongs_to_many :developers, after_add: :evaluate_velocity

  def evaluate_velocity(developer)
    ...
  end
end
```

> Extensions
>
> The extension argument allows you to pass a block into a
>   has_and_belongs_to_many association. This is useful for adding new finders, > creators and other factory-type methods to be used as part of
>   the association.

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :contractors do
  def find_or_create_by_name(name)
    first_name, last_name = name.split(" ", 2)
    find_or_create_by(first_name: first_name, last_name: last_name)
  end
end
```

> Extensions can refer to the internals of the association proxy using
>   these three attributes of the proxy_association accessor:

```
proxy_association.owner returns the object that the association is a part of. 
proxy_association.reflection returns the reflection object that describes the association. 
proxy_association.target returns the associated object for belongs_to or has_one, or the collection of associated objects for has_many or has_and_belongs_to_many.
```

Comment: sorry for the slow response, added some more info, I currently use a has many through, sorry updated the title

Answer (score 0):

Your relationships between models cannot be represented by a join table. They need to be represented by a regular, model table (and it needs id, created_at, updated_at). They should all be regular, ActiveRecord::Base models.

In this case, you have a **join model**, Affiliation, and not a join table

So for all three, you need a regular active record base table (containing id, created_at, updated_at)

Join tables are only used for **has_and_belongs_to_many** associations, and these do allow tables with no id, created_at, updated_at

Comment: I believe all of them are normal active record models, the "ApplicationRecord" is what models inherit from in Rails 5, no idea why but they changed the base object names  http://blog.bigbinary.com/2015/12/28/application-record-in-rails-5.html